# How to use Curl to post contents of file in a form

Tags: file, post, curl

I'm trying to post a list of identifiers as a form value from a file using curl. I've tried many different formats but each time the filename is posted rather than the actual data.

An example I have tried is below:

```
curl http:localhost:<port>/test --data "userId=User" --data "uploadIds=<test.txt"

curl http:localhost:<port>/test --data "userId=User" --data "uploadIds=@test.txt"
```

each of the above results in the filename being posted.

The file contains a comma-separated list of numbers.

Comment: From your question I'm not sure whether this is a curl question or a general "is not working" question. Keep in mind, that when you upload a file via HTTP, it's contents is sent in the body, not as parameter.

Comment: thanks for the response, I've reworded the question to remove references to parameters as its misleading, I don't want to upload the actual file, just use the file content to populate the data in the form so for example the result would be uploadIds=12345,6789

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, the syntax I was looking for is:

```
curl http:localhost:<port>/test --data "userId=User" --data-urlencode uploadIds@test.txt
```